# for loop didnt read all rows in my csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I have 6 rows in my original file
but when I run the script using pandas and for loop, it only read the first 4 rows
when I tried to print(original.shape) it's showing the correct amount of rows / 6rows

```
original=pd.read_csv('csv1.csv')
new=pd.read_csv('csv2.csv')
rn=0
for row in original:
  new.loc[rn,'listid']=int(original.loc[rn,'listid'])**3
  new.loc[rn,'name']=original.loc[rn,'name']
  new.loc[rn,'country']=original.loc[rn,'country']
  dateinput=original.loc[rn,'dob']
  if date_matchingdob(dateinput) == True:
    new.loc[rn,'dob']=datetime.strptime(dateinput, '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y%m%d')
  elif date_matchingyob(dateinput) == True:
    new.loc[rn,'yearofbirth']=dateinput
  new.to_csv('csv2.csv', index=False)
  rn+=1
print(new)
```

i tried to print the row using for loop

```
for row in original:
    print(rn)
    rn+=1

it only print 0,1,2,3 so only 4 rows are being read. 
looks like because there's only 4column in the file. how do i make the for loop to read the row instead of column?
```

Comment: i have 6rows now, i tried to check how many row read by for loops using this code
```
original=pd.read_csv('csv3.csv')
new=pd.read_csv('csv4.csv')
rn=0
for row in original:
 print(rn)
 rn+=1
```

it only print 0 ,1,2,3 so the for loops only read 4 rows. do you know what is the issue?

Comment: What do you think: `for row in original:` does when `original` is a pandas dataframe? Have you tried to see?

Comment: when i print for row in original, actually the for loop reading the total of column instead of row

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding the count of the original csv and run it in to for loop
I'm not sure whether is there any other way to fix this?

```
original=pd.read_csv('csv1.csv')
new=pd.read_csv('csv2.csv')
csvoriginal=csv.reader(open('csv1.csv'))
count=len(list(csvoriginal))
rn=0
id=0
for sub in range(1,count):
  dateinput=str(original.loc[rn,'dob'])
  id=id+1
  if date_matchingdob(dateinput) == True:
    new.loc[rn,'dob']=datetime.strptime(dateinput, '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y%m%d')
  elif date_matchingyob(dateinput) == True:
    new.loc[rn,'yearofbirth']=str(dateinput)
  new.loc[rn,'id']=str(id)
  new.loc[rn,'name']=original.loc[rn,'name']
  new.loc[rn,'country']=original.loc[rn,'country']
  rn+=1
  new.to_csv('csv2.csv', index=False)
print(new)
```